Different values between auc obtained from cross_validate and RocCurveDisplay
I tried two ways to calculate AUC score after training a Random Forest classifier. The first one is obtaining the metric from the cross_validate function:
numeric_transformer = make_pipeline(
    IterativeImputer(estimator=RandomForestRegressor(),random_state=0),
    StandardScaler()
)
preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
    (numeric_transformer, numeric_cols)
)


pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
])

scoring = {
    'AUC': 'roc_auc', 
    'ACCURACY': 'accuracy',
    'F1_SCORE': 'f1',
    'PRECISION': 'precision',
    'RECALL': 'recall'
}
print(scoring)

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
cv_scores_RF = cross_validate(pipe, X, y, cv=cv, scoring=scoring, return_estimator=True)

print("Random forest metrics")
print(f"AUC: {abs(cv_scores_RF['test_AUC']).mean()}")
print(f"ACCURACY: {cv_scores_RF['test_ACCURACY'].mean()}")
print(f"F1 SCORE: {abs(cv_scores_RF['test_F1_SCORE']).mean()}")
print(f"PRECISION: {abs(cv_scores_RF['test_PRECISION']).mean()}")
print(f"RECALL: {abs(cv_scores_RF['test_RECALL']).mean()}")


With the code above I obtain an AUC of 0.72.
Then i plotted the ROC curve with the function RocCurveDisplay:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))


tprs = []
aucs = []


for i, estimator in enumerate(cv_scores_RF['estimator']):
    viz = RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(estimator, X, y, ax=plt.gca(), name=f'ROC fold {i+1}')
    
    roc_auc = auc(viz.fpr, viz.tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)

    interp_tpr = np.interp(mean_fpr, viz.fpr, viz.tpr)
    interp_tpr[0] = 0.0
    tprs.append(interp_tpr)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_auc = np.mean(aucs)

plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b', linestyle='--', lw=2, label=f'Mean ROC (AUC = {mean_auc:.2f})')

plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) - RF')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

plt.show()

print(f"Mean AUC: {mean_auc:.2f}")


But plotting the curve the AUC I got in the graph is of 0.97. Why does this happen?
I expected to get similar values, for example I changed the classifier to SVM and got different values too. From the metrics obtained by cross_validate I got 0.53 AUC, but from RocCurveDisplay, 0.71. Also trying with Naive Bayes, in this case, i got very similar values, 0.66 and 0.68 respectively.

maybe you should ask experts on similar portal DataScience or CrossValidated

The main problem is that your second approach computes the AUC of each fold's model on the entire data set:
    viz = RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(estimator, X, y, ax=plt.gca(), name=f'ROC fold {i+1}')

Since this includes the data folds that the model was trained on, the scores are optimistically biased.
